# How to understand the "echo ${ALL%.*}"?

Tags: bash

the codes:

```
#! /bin/bash 

ALL="hello.log"
echo ${ALL%.*}
```

I know the "hello" will show, But how to understand the **"${ALL%.*}"**?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ }` is used for expansion  and `%.*` is used for remove from echo all characters contained in `ALL` variable from fullstop on.

Comment: @lxgeek, specifically, remove characters from the *last* dot onward. If you want to delete the *first* dot and subsequent chars, use `${ALL%%.*}`. Documented in the bash manual under "shell parameter expansion".

Answer (score 2):

Lets break this down;

```
${ALL%.*}
```

- `${ }` - Uses [Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
- `ALL` - Variable name.
- `%` - Remove beginning from the end of the string (RHS)(non greedy).
- `.*` - Pattern matching expression; a literal dot followed by any character.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *Parameter Expansion*. It's documented in the corresponding section of the manual that you can see by typing `man bash`. Search for `${parameter%word}`.